# can't erase drawn lines more than once with quartz 2d drawing app

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, drawing, quartz-2d

I'm making a draw app and what I do is to load an image from camera roll in a previous view controller, and send it to here, and load it in mainImage, then the app do some drawing in the photo. Now if I choose the eraser tool, I can erase what the app has drawn but it works only the first time I erase, because when I release my first touch and try to erase again it does nothing. Even If I choose another button to draw some other lines and then choose the eraser again, it doesn't erase. Can Anybody help me with this?

```
@synthesize mainImage;
@synthesize tempDrawImage;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    red = 255.0/255.0;
    green = 0/255.0;
    blue = 255.0/255.0;
    brush = 10.0;
    opacity = 1.0;
    self.mainImage.image = [camViewController image]; //load photo from camera roll from previous view controller
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //draw line in the middle of the screen
    [self drawMiddleRectangleBrushSize:20];

}

-(void)drawMiddleRectangleBrushSize:(float)brushSize{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size);
    [self.tempDrawImage.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
    CGContextMoveToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), self.view.frame.size.width/2, 0);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), self.view.frame.size.width/2, self.view.frame.size.height);
    CGContextSetLineCap(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGLineCapRound);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), brushSize );
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), red, green, blue, 1.0);
    CGContextSetBlendMode(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(),kCGBlendModeNormal);

    CGContextStrokePath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
    self.tempDrawImage.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    [self.tempDrawImage setAlpha:opacity];
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
}

- (IBAction)pencilPressed:(id)sender {

    UIButton * PressedButton = (UIButton*)sender;
    _eraserPress = NO;
    switch(PressedButton.tag)
    {
        case 0:
            red = 0.0/255.0;
            green = 0.0/255.0;
            blue = 0.0/255.0;
            break;
        case 1:
            red = 105.0/255.0;
            green = 105.0/255.0;
            blue = 105.0/255.0;
            break;
        case 2:
            red = 255.0/255.0;
            green = 0.0/255.0;
            blue = 0.0/255.0;
            break;
        case 3:
            red = 0.0/255.0;
            green = 0.0/255.0;
            blue = 255.0/255.0;
            break;
        case 4:
            red = 102.0/255.0;
            green = 204.0/255.0;
            blue = 0.0/255.0;
            break;
        case 5:
            red = 102.0/255.0;
            green = 255.0/255.0;
            blue = 0.0/255.0;
            break;
        case 6:
            red = 51.0/255.0;
            green = 204.0/255.0;
            blue = 255.0/255.0;
            break;
        case 7:
            red = 160.0/255.0;
            green = 82.0/255.0;
            blue = 45.0/255.0;
            break;
        case 8:
            red = 255.0/255.0;
            green = 102.0/255.0;
            blue = 0.0/255.0;
            break;
        case 9:
            red = 255.0/255.0;
            green = 255.0/255.0;
            blue = 0.0/255.0;
            break;
    }
}

- (IBAction)eraserPressed:(id)sender {

    red = 255.0/255.0;
    green = 255.0/255.0;
    blue = 255.0/255.0;
    opacity = 1.0;
    _eraserPress = YES;
}

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    mouseSwiped = NO;
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    lastPoint = [touch locationInView:self.view];
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    mouseSwiped = YES;
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint currentPoint = [touch locationInView:self.view];

    if(_eraserPress == NO){

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size);
    [self.tempDrawImage.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
    CGContextMoveToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), currentPoint.x, currentPoint.y);
    CGContextSetLineCap(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGLineCapRound);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), brush );
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), red, green, blue, 1.0);
    CGContextSetBlendMode(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(),kCGBlendModeNormal);

    CGContextStrokePath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
    self.tempDrawImage.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    [self.tempDrawImage setAlpha:opacity];
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    lastPoint = currentPoint;
    }
    if(_eraserPress == YES){
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size);
        [self.tempDrawImage.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];

        CGContextSetLineCap(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGLineCapRound);
        CGContextSetLineWidth(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(),brush);
        CGContextSetBlendMode(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGBlendModeClear);

        CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), red, green, blue, 1.0);
        CGContextBeginPath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
        CGContextSetShouldAntialias(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), YES);
        CGContextSetAllowsAntialiasing(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), YES);
        CGContextMoveToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y);
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), currentPoint.x, currentPoint.y);
        CGContextStrokePath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
        CGContextSetFlatness(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 0.1f);
        self.tempDrawImage.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    }
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    if(!mouseSwiped) {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size);
        [self.tempDrawImage.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
        CGContextSetLineCap(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGLineCapRound);
        CGContextSetLineWidth(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), brush);
        CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), red, green, blue, opacity);
        CGContextMoveToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y);
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y);
        CGContextStrokePath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
        CGContextFlush(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
        self.tempDrawImage.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    }

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.mainImage.frame.size);
    [self.mainImage.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height) blendMode:kCGBlendModeNormal alpha:1.0];
    [self.tempDrawImage.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height) blendMode:kCGBlendModeNormal alpha:opacity];
    self.mainImage.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    self.tempDrawImage.image = nil;
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `touchesMoved` method when you're in "erase mode", you are not updating your `lastPoint`. This could be what's causing your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I've done it commenting these two lines of code that merge the two images, and when both images are merged in to one, you can't erase anymore. Hope it helps somebody, cheers!

```
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    if(!mouseSwiped) {
    //code...
    }
    //self.mainImage.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    //self.tempDrawImage.image = nil;
}
```